# Limiting a razor element length when filling it with a list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I have a list of strings. ex. "dog", "cat", "horse"

```
List<string> selectedStyles = new List<string>();
```

and I want to put them into a label or some razor element that will allow me to limit the length. So if the length is greater then ex. 500px then it goes down into the next row. What can I use instead of a HTML.Label() ?

The key is that I want it to look like a label. ex. no borders, etc.

Comment: Not clear what your asking If you have say 10 items, do you want to display say 4 on the first line, then the next 4 on the second line and the last 2 on the last line?

Comment: no. the number of items on a row is irreverent. It's the length of each row that I want to remain constant. Say I have 10 items like you say. The first 4 items fill up the label to a certain length (say 500px) then a new row will be created for the next N items that fill up to but no more then 500PX, then if more items exist a new row will be filled, etc, etc.

Comment: kinda like MS Word. you can have so many words per line. but I'm not sure if this would be a label or some other element

Comment: Then why not just use`String.Join()` to create a single `string`and then render it inside a `<div>` element styled to `width: 500px;`

Comment: I think I got it. I used a label with a max-width. now it is puttingthe joined string with items on multiple rows!

Comment: Dont use a `<label>` - A label is as accessibility element - when you click on it, it sets focus to its associated control (and you do not have one!)